# How to redirect my AWS service catalog older version to new version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-catalog

I have a created a service catalog product version `v1.0.0`

**User a and User b**  is using my product version `v1.0.0` .

Now i have created a new version of the same product which is `v1.0.1`

`User d and User e` are using version `v1.0.1` .

I want to deactivate the version `v1.0.0` but when the User a and User b is already using the version.

I want to redirect the `User a User b` to get redirected to my newer version which is `v1.0.1` .

How can i do this in AWS service catalog ????

Comment: I take it you have informed the user and that the newer version is interface compatible ?

Answer (score 0):

User a needs to update the product provisioned to use version b. But if you want no one else to use version a, then just delete it. All products provision from version a can continue to run as if the version existed.